# Writing out file to delta lake produces different results from Data Frame read using Apache Spark on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have the following code on my databricks notebook

```
fulldf = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema",True).load("/databricks-datasets/flights/")

fulldf.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save('/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Full/')

df = fulldf.limit(10)
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save('/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Small/')
```

when I do a display on df I get the results I expect to see:

```
display(df)
```

[image]

As you can see there are ten rows with correct information

However, when I read the actual parquet saved to '/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Small/' using the following:

```
test = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Small/part-00000-d9d24a80-28d6-43f5-950f-3c53a7d1336a-c000.snappy.parquet')

display(test)
```

I get a completely different result (although it should be the exact same result)

[image]

This is so strange.

I believe the problem is with limiting the results to 10 rows, but I don't see why I should get a completely different result

Comment: No, that was not what happened. If you would have tried reading a  Parquet file from a Delta directory, you would have got the following error: "Incompatible format detected.

A transaction log for Databricks Delta was found at `/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Small/_delta_log`,
but you are trying to read from `/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Small/part-00000-d9d24a80-28d6-43f5-950f-3c53a7d1336a-c000.snappy.parquet` using format("parquet"). You must use
'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table."

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised you even got output. On Databricks I got nothing but an error with your read approach.

As it is a `delta` file / sub directory and you must use the `delta` format therefore. Sure, it uses `parquet` underneath, but you need to use the `delta api`.

E.g.

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/AAAGed")
```

and

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/AAAGed")
```

and apply partitioning - if present, with a filter.

Comment: bluephantom, I'm not sure what you're suggesting .. I recreated the databricks notebook from here and it worked fine when they carried out the demonstration https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OQGEc09xbY&list=PLOmMQN2IKdjvowfXo_7hnFJHjcE3JOKwu&index=47&t=645s

Comment: Well i also use databricks.

Comment: I have done courses with errors in them.

Comment: Not how I understood it.

Comment: Have you had a chance to view the demonstration?

Comment: I need not but i tried all your code and it did not work

Comment: Oh, so you’re agreeing with me that it should work, correct? Meaning I shouldn’t be getting the result I’m getting with ‘flights’

Comment: No the code i run based on yours makes no sense as the answer states. Delta is a layer on top of larquet and one never reads the underlying files.

Comment: I am not sure why you raise a question and the commenter and me say , yes it does not work like that, but you feel you need not consider the answer valid. I tried all your code and from experience can tell it is not valid and then all the messages that come. I have found quite a few mistakes in the databricks courses,

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, while limiting the data to 10 rows. Writing it on the delta location, creating a table.  I am getting the same scattered data.